# How can I speed up numpy max (axis=1)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, max

I have a matrix (numpy array) of shape ~(30000, 2000).

I'm trying to get the max value of each row of this matrix. What I am doing is:

`(matrix).max(axis=1)`

This works as expected, but how can I speed up this computation?

I have to do this several times in my program, and this computation is consuming most part of execution time. Just to get an ideia, this is the output of profiling with regard to doing this operation 20x (using cProfile):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall   filename:lineno(function)
 20      0.000    0.000    0.580    0.029     {method 'max' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
 24      0.580    0.024    0.580    0.024     {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
```

This `{method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}` is the part that takes the most time, actually. But when I remove the max operation, this also disappear.

Any ideas on how to speed up this max operation (along axis=1)?

Comment: Try `numexpr` : `import numexpr as ne;
ne.evaluate('max(matrix,1)')`.

Comment: Strangely, this is slower than the above mentioned numpy approach (about 2x slower here)...

Comment: If it's being run repeatedly, you could look into numba.  A bit more overhead on first run, but usually much faster in later runs

Comment: What is the datatype of the matrix (see `matrix.dtype`)? Is it float64? Can you provide information about your processor and your RAM (especially the frequency)? @Divakar Note that the numexpr expression is curiously not executed in parallel.

Comment: matrix.dtype is np.float32; Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz; 4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz

Comment: `numexpr` needs multiple cores for effciency. How many coes does it have?

Comment: It has 2 cores and 4 threads

Comment: Your computation is almost memory-bound: with 29 ms to do this operation, the RAM throughput is 7.7Gio/s which is already quite good because your RAM can only reach 15.9Gio/s (if you have only 1 DIMM). Thus, 48.5% of the theoretical RAM maximum throughput is used. The best you can achieve is a speed-up of 2 (in practice, note that processors often barely use more than 90% of the theoretical maximum RAM throughput). @Divakar I have 6 cores and numexpr uses only one core for computing  this expression.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Did you try setting it to 6 and more with `ne.set_num_threads(nthreads=6)`? AFAIK should be leveraging multi-cores

Comment: @JérômeRichard does this means that if I get more RAM it will be faster? Can't get faster with this setup? Sorry, I'm not much acquainted to these technical details. To be more specific, when I execute ``a = np.random.rand(30000, 2000); %timeit [a.max(axis=1) for _ in range(20)]``, my output is: ``805 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)``

Comment: I've tried comparing the numpy vs. numexpr approach in another machine with this configuration: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550  @ 2.67GHz (4 cores/8 threads); 32GB RAM; I've made the comparison using: ``%timeit ne.evaluate('max(a, 1)')`` vs ``%timeit a.max(axis=1)``. With numpy I got 40.1 ms and with numexpr 157 ms.

Comment: I guess that the computation is bounded by your CPU so far. But, If you use a bit faster approach, then you will be bounded by your RAM. In this case, you will need to rewrite your code so that computed data fit in the CPU cache (and if you cannot, then there is no solution than changing hardware). @Divakar still the same with that. I got similar result to the one of Matheus Müller.

Comment: A better way to speed up is probably to avoid creating the full matrix in the first place, if you can, and instead doing a max row-by-row in a loop (accelerated with Numba).